Limit PM2-Health Alerts
I want to limit the exception alerts sent by PM2. Specifically, if an application crashes and an exception occurs, PM2 should send an alert immediately but wait at least 5 minutes before sending the next alert. Currently, I receive an email every minute whenever an exception occurs.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
